# How is the Stream-cons #:: translated in Scala?

Tags: scala

I'm currently learning Scala by working through the "Programming in Scala" book. So far, there have been nice explanations for everything that looks weird (from a Java programmer's perspective), but this one example using a Stream to generate the Fibonacci sequence leaves me kind of puzzled:

```
def fibFrom(a: Int, b: Int): Stream[Int] =
  a #:: fibFrom(b, a + b)
```

How is the construction of the Stream done? Of course the `#::` operator is somehow responsible for that. I understand that since it ends in `:`, it is right-associative, but that does not explain the creation of the Stream. I guess it is implicitly translated to a constructor somehow but I don't see why and how exactly.

I've already looked for answers in `Predef.scala` and `LowPriorityImplicits.scala` but no luck so far.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is right associative so it works as a method on the right argument:

```
fibFrom(b, a + b).#::(a)
```

At least that is what it tries to do syntactically. `Stream[Int]` does not have such a method. Luckily though, `object Stream` has an implicit to some class `ConsWrapper` which has this method ([code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Stream.scala#L1022)).

So, what you get after implicit resolution is this:

```
immutable.this.Stream.consWrapper(fibFrom(b, a + b)).#::(a)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it. I forgot that implicit conversions can also be defined in the companion object of the class that should be converted.

Comment: Scaladoc should probably automatically include those hard-coded companion implicits.

Comment: Maybe point out to others new to Scala that it isn't _just_ that it's right-associative. It's also that the ConsWrapper implements `#::` as [call-by-name](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Stream.scala#L1042). i.e. the `⇒` in `ConsWrapper(tl: ⇒ Stream[A])` so that the translation into `immutable.this.Stream.consWrapper(fibFrom(b, a + b)).#::(a)` means `fibFrom(b, a + b)` will only ever be called when accessed.

Answer (score 2):

A Stream is similar to a List. It knows only its head and the rest of the stream: Stream(head: T, tail: Stream[T]). The difference is, that a Stream is evaluated lazily. The ':' at the end of the name of the method says that the method is right associative. So the expression a #:: fibFrom(b, a + b) is translated (by the compiler) to fibFrom(b, a + b).#::(a).

Comment: Thanks, that's what I figured, but it does not explain how the Stream object is created. If Stream had a method `#::`, this would cause an infinite recursion I guess.

Comment: The #:: is the same as :: in List. And yes it is an infinite recursion. You just take the number of elements you want. That was what I wanted to express by telling it is lazily evaluated. This means it will be just computed when there is need for computing.

Comment: It is not exactly the same, no. If it were the same, the you would have an infinite recursion there. Instead, `#::` (defined in Class `ConsWrapper`, not Stream!) has a by-name parameter which is evaluated lazily.

Comment: You are right it was not adequate to say it is the same similar would be better.